# Android studio 1.5.1 'Rendering problems' error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android packages for 4.4, 5 and 6 installed in my android sdk. When i reduce the API level from 23 to 19(android 4.4). i get the following error:

------Rendering problems----

> The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate
>
> -porterDuff Color filters are not supported

please how can solve this

Comment: @abhinav, what's radius?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this by clicking the refresh button close to the mobile phone image. If this doesn't work, then consider reinstalling android studio.